# Word wrap not working in UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

Below result, for `UILabel`. it only happens if the word is too long.

[image]

Below is something I want to achieve. It works if I reduce the Lable height. but Label height is dynamic

[image]

Help appreciate.
Thank you

Comment: Is this a fix word/string `CHULALONGKORN UNIVERSITY`, which you want set in two lines. Or this string may change?

Comment: No, this is a dynamic string. but i found this issue for "CHULALONGKORN UNIVERSITY"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.  It should shrink the font just enough to fit the longest word on a line.  If you see a better way let me know as I would love to improve this.I am sure I could adapt it to work in IB.

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel{

    func adjustedFont()->UIFont {
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: font]
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text ?? "", attributes: attributes)
        let drawingContext = NSStringDrawingContext()
        drawingContext.minimumScaleFactor = minimumScaleFactor

        attributedString.boundingRect(with: bounds.integral.size,
                                      options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                      context: drawingContext)

        let fontSize = font.pointSize * drawingContext.actualScaleFactor

        return font.withSize(fontSize)
    }

    func fitMaxWord(){
        layoutIfNeeded()
        let scaledFont = self.adjustedFont()
        let currentFont = scaledFont
        if let txt = text,
            let maxString = txt.components(separatedBy: " ").max(by: {$1.count > $0.count})?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ""){
            let maxFontSize: CGFloat = currentFont.pointSize
            let minFontSize: CGFloat = 5.0


            var q = maxFontSize
            var p = minFontSize
            let height = currentFont.lineHeight
            let constraintSize = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
            var sizedFont = currentFont
            while(p <= q){
                let currentSize = (p + q) / CGFloat(2)
                sizedFont = currentFont.withSize( CGFloat(currentSize) )

                let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string:maxString, attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font:sizedFont])

                let textRect = text.boundingRect(with: constraintSize, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil).integral
                let labelSize = textRect.width

                //1 is a fudge factor
                if labelSize == ceil(self.bounds.width - 1){
                    break
                }else if labelSize > ceil(self.bounds.width - 1){
                    q = currentSize - 0.1
                }else{
                    p = currentSize + 0.1
                }
            }

            if sizedFont.pointSize < currentFont.pointSize{
                self.font = sizedFont
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Minimum example:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //we could test longer text
        //
        let text = "CHULALONGKORN UNIVERSITY Plus a lot of additional text to make sure it still does not clip a word"
        let testLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        //testLabel.text = "CHULALONGKORN UNIVERSITY"
        testLabel.text = text
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.textAlignment = .center
        testLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45)
        testLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true //unneeded in this instance but lets set it
        testLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.3
        self.view.addSubview(testLabel)
        testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        testLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        testLabel.fitMaxWord()
    }


}
```

[image: ExampleImage]
This should work in most circumstances.  I tested with your text and more text.  You can see both in the example above.

Comment: I'll check. Thank you

Comment: This will work with your current situation but I can think of one improvement to be made to make it work with any. I have terrible Internet connection and so it will be about an hour or so

Comment: @RomitM  Give it a go now. You could test your IB example just calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() then the extension on the label the same as above.  I made it work for more text and getting the current font size that may be dynamic if scaling is enabled.

Comment: just promise if you find a better way to comment back here.

Comment: sure I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out all lineBreakMode modes will pass characters on another line when the word is bigger than that line. 
It seems that the only way to fix it is to change font size to fit this word. Autoshrink has some limitations and does not detect splitting word to several lines, so you need manually detect that word is not fitted and change font size accordingly.

Question with the same problem: [How to make multi-line UILabel text fit within predefined width without wrapping mid-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42890965/how-to-make-multi-line-uilabel-text-fit-within-predefined-width-without-wrapping)

Answer (score -1):

You can set constraint as your requirement for a label. suppose if you don't want fix height then It's not necessary to set bottom constraint.

See below image I have set a constraint for dynamic label height. Hope this will help you.

[image: constraint]
[image: properties]

Comment: But iphone have a limitation of device size. Iphone have max 414 width

Comment: So just need to decrease the size of font.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution to your problem if, your string has fixed value, as you've shown in your question (i.e. `CHULALONGKORN UNIVERSITY`).

Set following properties for your label in your interface builder.

1. Set your label text value in two lines, as shown in below snapshot (not in a single line like - `CHULALONGKORN UNIVERSITY`). Press <kbd>alt + enter</kbd> inplace of space between two words.
2. Set number of lines = 2
3. Set line break mode = Truncate Tail
4. Set Autoshrink to `Minimum Font Scale' and value for scale to`0.5` or whatever minimum scale you like to set.

-
[image]

Answer (score -2):

you should try UILabel alignment justified[image]

Comment: as `Romit` clearly write that `Label height is dynamic`.

Comment: you should try auto layout , check this link http://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/using-autolayout-to-dynamically-resize-uilabel/

Comment: I tried that's not working and I have to keep align center.

Comment: yourLabelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

Answer (score -2):

whenever you give **label** height as **Dynamic**

Select the **Lines** Count as 0 in Attributes Inspector[image]

Then automatically based on the Content of **label** the height is increases.